# <mark> text across <li> elements with hover behavior in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Suppose I have HTML / JSX like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>First bullet point</li>
  <li>Second bullet point</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to highlight a range that "spans" multiple list elements "contiguously":

```
<ul>
  <li>First bullet <mark>point</mark></li>
  <li><mark>Second bullet</mark> point</li>
</ul>
```

Lastly, I'd like to add behaviour such that hovering over the first `<mark>` tags will trigger something for the second `<mark>` tags and vice versa. From the user's perspective, it should look and feel like a single `<mark>` tag.

Can this be done exclusively with CSS / Tailwind? Based on what I've seen so far, the sibling `~` combinator [can only be used on earlier elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502693/) to affect later elements. The same appears to be true for the [`peer` class in Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-sibling-state).

If Javascript is required, can someone point me in the right direction? FWIW, this is for a React project so there may be some caveats to manipulating the DOM directly.

Comment: Css can not go backwards up the tree. Is it highlighting all marks that are in the UL? That can be done with CSS. Or if there is multiple marks it only highlights those? If that is the case, you need JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello There may be multiple marks in the `<ul>`.

Comment: So if it is `<li>foo<mark>xxxx</mark>bar</li>` it should not select the next or prev?

Comment: @epascarello Say for example `<li>foo<mark>xxxx</mark>bar</li>` was the 3rd list element (after the first two in the example code), then hovering over `<mark>xxx</mark>` would not affect the prior two marks and vice versa.

Comment: So any mark is hovered they all will be highligthed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If hovering over any mark will also "hover" every other mark, then it is a simple has() call.

```css
ul:has(mark:hover) mark {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>First bullet </span><mark>point</mark></li>
  <li><mark>Second bullet</mark><span> point</span></li>
  <li><span>Third bullet </span><mark>point</mark></li>
  <li><mark>Fourth bullet</mark><span> point</span></li>
  <li><span>The </span><mark>Fifth bullet</mark><span> point</span></li>
</ul>
```

2. If hovering over a mark only "hovers" marks that are contiguous, then it is a bit more complicated.

```css
li mark:hover,
li:has(mark:last-child:hover) + li > mark:first-child,
li:has(mark:last-child):has(+ li > mark:first-child:hover) mark {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>First bullet </span><mark>point</mark></li>
  <li><mark>Second bullet</mark><span> point</span></li>
  <li><span>Third bullet </span><mark>point</mark></li>
  <li><mark>Fourth bullet</mark><span> point</span></li>
  <li><span>The </span><mark>Fifth bullet</mark><span> point</span></li>
</ul>
```

3. Since `:has()` is not enabled by default on Firefox (as of v109), here's a workaround using JavaScript.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

const removeActive = function (evt) {
  const active = evt.currentTarget.querySelector("mark.active");
  if (active) active.classList.remove("active");
}

ul.addEventListener("mouseover", function (evt) {
  removeActive(evt);
  let elem = null;

  const mark = evt.target.closest("mark");
  if (!mark) return;
  
  const li = mark.closest("li");
  
  if (!mark.previousSibling) {
    const prevLi = li.previousElementSibling;
    elem = prevLi && prevLi.lastChild;
  } else if (!mark.nextSibling) {
    const nextLi = li.nextElementSibling;
    elem = nextLi && nextLi.firstChild;
  }
  
  if (elem && elem.nodeName == "MARK") {
    elem.classList.add("active");
  }
});

ul.addEventListener("mouseleave", removeActive);
```

```css
li mark:hover,
li mark.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First bullet <mark>point</mark></li>
  <li><mark>Second bullet</mark> point</li>
  <li>Third bullet <mark>point</mark></li>
  <li><mark>Fourth bullet</mark> point</li>
  <li>The </span><mark>Fifth bullet</mark><span> point</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was primarily interested in the latter case and this solution is pretty slick. The only caveat is that `:has` is still not available by default on Firefox (as of [v109](https://caniuse.com/css-has)). Is there a workaround without a parent selector?

Comment: alternative is JavaScript